# How can I get the ListPicker control under Manipulate to update on the fly?

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

It does update when I `Show` or `Minimize` the Suggestions Bar, but I would like it to update automatically.

```
list = {1, 2, 3};

Dynamic[Manipulate[{If[addchoice != {}, 
AppendTo[list, Last[addchoice]]; addchoice = {}], list, 
addchoice}, {{addchoice, {}}, 
ListPicker[#1, list, Multiselection -> False] &}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a little easier with a [`ButtonBar`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ButtonBar.html).

With

```
list = {1, 2, 3};
Manipulate[
 # :> AppendTo[list, #] & /@ list // ButtonBar,
 {n, None}]
```

`n` is there as a placeholder for `Manipulate`. No doubt this snippet will be used in a larger `Manipulate`.  If not you can use `Dynamic` instead of `Manipulate` and remove the `n` bit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is really cool! :) But I was hoping for a vertical listing with a scroll bar as the list grew.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a `Dynamic` expression for the list of values for your control. `Manipulate` will then automatically wrap the entire control in `Dynamic` if necessary:

```
list = {1, 2, 3};

Manipulate[
 {
  If[addchoice != {}, AppendTo[list, Last[addchoice]]; addchoice = {}],
  list,
  addchoice
  },
 {
  {addchoice, {}},
  Dynamic@list,
  ControlType -> ListPicker,
  Multiselection -> False
  }
 ]
```

[image: animation]

Note that I have used the [`ControlType`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ControlType.html) option to set the type of control, while the `Multiselection` option was simply appended to the variable specification.